# Can a higher P/E ratio be beneficial under certain circumstances?

Tags: data, equities, trading, fundamentals

I am new to investing. I understand that the P/E ratio along with other data can be used to determine whether a stock may or may not be undervalued.

Are there situations where a HIGH P/E is actually beneficial? Say for instance you have a stock with a P/E of 20. If the earnings-per-share on that stock increases by $1, you would expect that **if the P/E ratio remains constant** then the price of the stock would increase by $20. It is somewhat counter-intuitive that a high P/E would be desirable, but it stands to reason that if the market is willing to pay 20x earnings when earnings are at X, why wouldn't the market be willing to pay 20x earnings (or perhaps even more) when earnings move to X + 1.

I think I read something along these lines in Burton Malkiel's book but I am not positive, any thoughts on this concept or research in that area I could look into? What considerations can we make with respect to whether its reasonable to assume that the P/E ratio will remain constant, increase, or decrease?

Comment: I am curious why SE doesn't have place for professional research analyst yet? Even the new proposal, "Stock Investing", doesn't look like for professional fundamental research analyst or portfolio manager. The sample questions look more like for proprietary traders. As for Money.SE? I have to say it's more for amateur. Also, the topic there is too diverse.

Comment: If there is a SE for fundamentals research analyst, this is definitely a nice classical question! :) Sean, I wish I could answer your somewhere. What a pity that we don't have a place for you yet.

Comment: Professional fundamental analysis of a quantitative nature would be very welcome. This is a basic PE question, much more suitable for a  personal finance site.

Comment: @楊祝昇 I wouldn't really consider this question "professional", it may be welcome on money.SE, as it is a personal investing question.  Sean, let me turn the question around.  Why *would* the market be willing to pay 20x EPS after earnings rise?  If b/c the move was unexpected, then of course the stock will rise.  If the move was actually less than expected, the P/E will likely drop quite a bit.  The point is that P/Es are unstable, and high P/Es certainly aren't beneficial by themselves.

Comment: Well, I think it's a 'classical' question :) and an answer from a pro research analyst will be more educational than an answer from an amateur. I am sure a pro has an answer much better than you expect. But still, the main point is: this question surprised me that SE doesn't have a place for pro research analyst yet, while we have this site for pro quants.

Comment: @楊祝昇 Perhaps some day there will be, but at the moment there doesn't seem to be much demand, only 20 followers for [Investment Banking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30390/investment-banking) (note: this proposal is really more about professionals working at investment banks than banking per se).